# JavaScript - Show/Hide Without Refreshing Page

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help? I want to only show the script output if a particular application variable is true, without refreshing the page, as initially, the application variable could be false

```
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var quotes = new Array(
'Quote 1',
'Quote 2',
'Quote 3'
);
function rotate() {
    quote = quotes.shift();
    quotes.push(quote);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = quote;
    setTimeout("rotate()", 2000);
}
rotate();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: which variable you called. please explained properly. but if you want to show/hide without refresh the page just called the javascript on the control like: javascirpt: functionaname();return false; hope this help.

Comment: @Suresh Chaudhary - By application variable, I mean one that is available to the entire application (global to everyone). What I need is along the lines of a script that will call another page without displaying it, grab the variable, and pending if it is true or false, show or hide my script

Comment: instead of adding the script directly you need to check the variable at server side and if it return to true then registered the script like :  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "commentScr", "scriptname()", true);   hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use setInterval instead of setTimeout. Something like this:

```
function showQuotes()
{
    if(someVariable)
    {
        quote = quotes.shift();
        quotes.push(quote);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = quote;
    }
}
setInterval("showQuotes()",2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this, but I don't see how it is going to work. Please refer to my comment to Suresh Chaudhary (above) for more info